# How to pretty-print decimal format

Tags: ruby, decimal, number-formatting, pretty-print

Is there a way to change the default format of decimals when I pretty-print them?

```
irb(main):521:0> pp 10.to_d / 2.5   
0.4e1
```

I would like to format it as:

```
irb(main):521:0> pp 10.to_d / 2.5   
4.0
```

I don't really care about potential precision loss. The default format is especially annoying to read when you're pretty-printing Rails records:

```
<
  ...  
  id: 49391,  
  operator_id: 1,  
  tax_rate: 0.10e2,  
  sales_price: 0.1e2,  
  unit_price: 0.2e1,  
  >
```

I know that I can do `to_s` or `to_f`, etc., but the whole point of pretty-print is that I don't have to convert my records before I can have a quick glance at them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could monkey-patch the method the pretty-printer uses. "Normal" IRb uses `inspect`, but most of the pretty-printer libraries have their own methods.

For example, the [`pp` library](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/pp/rdoc/index.html) from the standard library uses a method called `pretty_print`. `BigDecimal` doesn't have its own implementation of `pretty_print` unfortunately, it simply inherits the one from `Numeric` which just delegates to `inspect`.

So, we can write our own!

```
class BigDecimal
  def pretty_print(pp)
    pp.text to_s('F')
  end
end

pp 10.to_d / 2.5
# 4.0
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

When you use `to_d` or `to_f` you're telling Ruby to convert the value to a BigDouble or Float, but that doesn't specify output format, which is a different problem.

Ruby supports string formatting in a couple flavors, but generally you define a format that is then used to "pretty-print" the output:

```
foo = 0.4e1
'%1.1f' % foo # => "4.0"
```

Note that the output is a string, not a Float or BigDecimal. Everything is converted to a String before being output to the console. Ruby's format strings follow the `sprintf` format strings used by C, Perl and many other languages. See [`sprintf`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) for more information.

And, while `sprintf` exists, I rarely see it used. Instead String's [`%`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-25) method is used more often, followed by Kernel's [`format`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Kernel.html#method-i-format) method.

Also note that `10.to_d / 2.5` is invalid because `10` is an Integer, and Integer doesn't know how to `to_d`:

```
10.class # => Integer
10.respond_to?(:to_d) # => false
10.to_d / 2.5    # => NoMethodError: undefined method `to_d' for 10:Integer
```

Requiring BigDecimal is necessary to get `to_d`:

```
require 'bigdecimal'
require 'bigdecimal/util'

10.to_d / 2.5    # => 0.4e1
```

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby 2.4, `BigDecimal#inspect` is equivalent to `BigDecimal#to_s` which always defaults to use the scientific notation.

```
decimal = 10.to_d / 2.5
decimal.inspect
# => "0.4e1"

# equivalent to
decimal.to_s
# => "0.4e1"
```

Fortunately, the class accepts an argument to its `to_s` method which allows you to specify the format of the resulting string. Among other options, you can specify if you want the scientific notation or the conventional floating point notation. Thus, by using it as follows, you can get your desired result:

```
decimal.to_s("F")
# => "4.0"
```

[The documentation of BigDecimal#to_s](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html#method-i-to_s) goes into detail how you can set further formatting options.

Unfortunately for your apparent use-case, there is no way in Ruby to change the default format. In order to get the floating point notation, you always have to explicitly add the `"F"` argument to the `to_s` method.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so this issue was bothering me, and I finally decided to do something about it. Here's my solution:

```
module BigDecimalForIrb
  def inspect
    to_s "F"
  end
end

BigDecimal.send :prepend, BigDecimalForIrb
```

You can add it directly to your .irbrc file. Or if you put it in a separate file, you have two choices: load it in .irbrc, or load it manually in your console whenever you want to use it.

(Note that `#prepend` is only available as of Ruby 2.0. If, for some crazy reason, you're still in Ruby 1.x, you can do something similar with `alias_method_chain`.)